# Is it possible to trade Pokémon from Silver virtual console to Fire Red or Diamond?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I can't find anything about this and it won't work. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to trade from second generation games to third or fourth generation games, whether the original release or the virtual console re-release.

Answer (score 0):

The Second Generation Pokémon games on the 3DS Virtual Console are only capable of either trading with another Virtual Console Pokemon Gen 1 or 2 Game (Red/Blue/Yellow/Gold/Silver), or transferring Pokemon to the [Pokémon Bank](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/) (Pokébank) Application (one-way transfer).

Pokemon transferred from first or second generation games are (currently) only able to be then transferred from the Pokébank to Sun/Moon (Generation 7). Thus Fire Red (Generation 3) and Diamond (Generation 4) **cannot receive Pokemon from the 3DS Virtual Console**.

Here's a graphic that shows where the Virtual Console ports sit in relation to the other games (taken from the [offical Pokemon Bank Website](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/bank/)):

[image: Pokemon Transfer Table]

More information can be found on the [Bulbapedia Virtual Console Page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Virtual_Console)